# lightning input file not working in modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninginput

I have this code:

```
 <lightning:input name="myFile" type="file" label="Attachment" required="true" onchange="{! c.handleFilesChange }"/>
```

It works fine when placed in component. 
But when it is placed in modal, it does not open file selector.
I use this modal: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/

Although drag and drop is working in both cases.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use overlay library?

Comment: @kurunve no, let me check it

Comment: @kurunve yes it helped. Please do post an answer so I can accept it